# Does DataTemplate in the resources set the datacontext of the view automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

in my window resources i have a datatemplate like the following

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:GoogleViewModel}">
            <Views:GoogleView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

does that mean if i bind the content of a UI elemnt to that view model it will load the view and set the datacontext of that view to the view model automatically, or i still have to set the datacontext for the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that will set the dataContext of the Viewmodel to the View Automatically. Always DataContext set to View not to the viewModel. That means Object of the ViewModel will be bind to the View not the other way.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer, the above xmal code will not set the DataContext of the ViewModel to the View. it will define only the Type that can be bound to the control on which that DataTemplate is applied

Comment: If you want to set the DataContext in the Xmal then you can do something like this     
<Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:GoogleViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>